# Shouldn't there be 3 antibonding orbitals for diatomic hydrogen?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, molecules, pauli-exclusion-principle

The bonding state of H<sub>2</sub> is |Ψ<sub>+</sub>>|0,0>. This makes sense because there is only 1 spatially symmetric state, in which the electrons experience an attractive exchange force. (|Ψ<sub>+</sub>> denotes spatial symmetry, |Ψ<sub>-</sub>> for spatial antisymmetry)

The antibonding orbital is formed by |Ψ<sub>+</sub>> and any of the three triplet spin states. However, shouldn't this allow for 3 antibonding orbitals?

|Ψ<sub>-</sub>>|1,1>, |Ψ<sub>-</sub>>|1,0>, |Ψ<sub>-</sub>>|1,-1> are all unique wavefunctions and thus unique quantum states. So the Pauli exclusion principle should not be violated since no more than 2 electrons would share the same total wavefunction.

So why can there only be 1 antibonding orbital for H<sub>2</sub>?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The (anti)bonding orbitals of a molecule typically refer to the spatial parts of single-particle states as computed under the independent electron approximation. In this approximation, when you bring two protons close to one another, the $1\mathrm s$ ground state orbital $|\psi_0\rangle$ of the isolated hydrogen atom splits into two orbitals $|\psi_a\rangle$ and $|\psi_b\rangle$ which are called the antibonding and bonding orbitals, respectively. The former is antisymmetric $\psi_a(-\mathbf x) = -\psi_a(\mathbf x)$ and the latter is symmetric $\psi_b(-\mathbf x)= \psi_b(\mathbf x)$ under **spatial inversion**; additionally, the former is has a higher energy than the latter. Therefore, the ground state of the single particle system is doubly-degenerate (due to spin) and is given by any linear combination of $|\psi_b\rangle \left|\uparrow\right>$ and $|\psi_b\rangle\left|\downarrow\right>$.  Observe that we are still talking about single particle states, and that Pauli exclusion plays no role yet.

If we wish to consider two-particle states, then the entire vector must be antisymmetric under **particle interchange** (not spatial inversion!).  The ground state of the two-particle system has spatial wavefunction $\Psi(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2) = \psi_b(\mathbf x_1)\psi_b(\mathbf x_2)$ (which is *symmetric* under particle interchange) and occupies the spin singlet state $(\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>-\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>)/\sqrt 2$ (which is *antisymmetric* under particle interchange).  As a result, the full ground state is antisymmetric under particle interchange $(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)\mapsto (\mathbf x_2,\mathbf x_1)$.

---

The next lowest energy state is obtained by having one particle in the bonding orbital and one particle in the antibonding orbital. The two-particle spatial wavefunction may be symmetric or antisymmetric, given by
$$\Psi_\pm (\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2) = \frac{\psi_b(\mathbf x_1)\psi_a(\mathbf x_2) \pm \psi_b(\mathbf x_2)\psi_a(\mathbf x_1)}{\sqrt{2}}$$

If the electrons have spatial wavefunction $\Psi_+$ which is symmetric under particle interchange, then the spin state must be the same antisymmetric singlet state as before:

$$|\Psi_+\rangle \left(\frac{\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right> - \left|\downarrow \uparrow\right>}{\sqrt{2}}\right) $$

On the other hand, if the electrons have joint wavefunction $\Psi_-$ which is antisymmetric under particle interchange, then the spin state must be (a linear combination of) one of the symmetric spin triplet states:

$$|\Psi_-\rangle\left|\uparrow\uparrow\right> \qquad |\Psi_-\rangle\left|\downarrow\downarrow\right> \qquad |\Psi_-\rangle\left(\frac{\left|\uparrow\downarrow\right>+\left|\downarrow\uparrow\right>}{\sqrt{2}}\right)$$

---

In summary:

1. The (anti)bonding orbitals refer to single particle states, which are (anti)symmetric under **spatial inversion**. The (spatially symmetric) bonding orbital has lower energy.
2. The Pauli exclusion principle doesn't care about *spatial* antisymmetry, it cares about antisymmetry under particle interchange.
3. The ground state of the 2-electron system has a wavefunction $\Psi(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)=\psi_b(\mathbf x_1)\psi_b(\mathbf x_2)$ which is **symmetric** under particle interchange and a spin singlet state which is **antisymmetric** under particle interchange.
4. The excited states may have a symmetric spatial wavefunction and antisymmetric (singlet) spin state, or an antisymmetric spatial wavefunction and symmetric (triplet) spin state. Again, the symmetry in question here is under particle interchange, not spatial inversion.

Comment: This seems off. I understand what you're trying to say with the single particle states but it's not clicking with me. To make sure I'm on the same page with notation, I define |Ψ+/-⟩ = [Ψ<sub>a</sub>(r1)Ψ<sub>b</sub>(r2) +/-  Ψ<sub>a</sub>(r2)Ψ<sub>b</sub>(r1)]. 

So the possible states are |Ψ+>|singlet> or  |Ψ->|triplet>. I don't think it's allowed for the antibonding orbital to have a symmetric spatial wave function. But not 100% sure on that.

Doesn't your explanation begin with the assumption that there are only 2 orbital states available?

Comment: @Dutonic I have substantially revised my answer in accordance with your clarified notation. The states you describe in your comment are *excited* states - the ground state of the H$_2$ molecule has the wavefunction $\Psi(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)=\psi_b(\mathbf x_1)\psi_b(\mathbf x_2)$ (which is symmetric both under particle interchange $(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)\mapsto (\mathbf x_2,\mathbf x_1)$ and spatial inversion $(\mathbf x_1,\mathbf x_2)\mapsto (-\mathbf x_1,-\mathbf x_2)$), and where $\psi_b$ is the single-particle, spatially symmetric **bonding orbital**.